# Pandas: how to drop rows that contain invalid month/day column combinations, such as February 30th?

Tags: python, pandas

I have source data that uses 31 columns for day values, with a row for each month. I've melted the 31 day columns into a single day column, and now I want to combine the year, month, and day columns into a datetime(?) column so I can sort the rows by year/month/day.

After the melt, my dataframe looks like so:

```
       year  month day   prcp
0      1893      1  01    0.0
1      1893      2  01    0.0
2      1893      3  01    0.0
3      1893      4  01    NaN
4      1893      5  01    NaN
5      1893      6  01    NaN
6      1893      7  01    NaN
7      1893      8  01    0.0
8      1893      9  01   10.0
9      1893     10  01    0.0
10     1893     11  01    0.0
11     1893     12  01    NaN
12     1894      1  01    NaN
13     1894      2  01    0.0
14     1894      3  01    NaN
...
```

Next I'm trying to create a 'time' column that I can sort on, using the year, month, and day columns as arguments to the datetime constructor. I've tried doing this using this approach:

```
def make_datetime(y, m, d):
    return(datetime(year=y, month=m, day=d))

df['time'] = np.vectorize(make_datetime)(df['year'].astype(int), df['month'].astype(int), df['day'].astype(int))
```

The above isn't going to get me there since it fails in cases where the month/day columns don't make sense together, such as February 29th during non-leap years, April 31st, etc. What I think I want to do next is to somehow wrap the datetime() call in a try/catch, and when it croaks due to incompatible month/day combinations I should drop the row within the catch block. How would I go about doing that without doing a for loop over all the rows? Or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your df derictly to `to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df,errors='coerce')
Out[905]: 
#          NaT
#          NaT
#   1892-02-29
#          NaT
#          NaT
#          NaT
#   1896-02-29
#          NaT
#          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
df['New']=pd.to_datetime(df,errors='coerce')
df.dropna()
Out[907]: 
   year  month  day        New
#  1892      2   29 1892-02-29
#  1896      2   29 1896-02-29
```

Comment: +1, very good. I would add that you can also select columns in case there are other columns in user's dataframe: `df['New']=pd.to_datetime(df[cols],errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using your suggestion of wrapping in a `try` / `except` clause.

```
from datetime import datetime

def dater(x):
    try:
        return datetime(year=x['year'], month=x['month'], day=x['day'])
    except ValueError:
        return None

df['date'] = df.apply(dater, axis=1)

#    year  month  day       date
# 0  1890      2   29        NaT
# 1  1891      2   29        NaT
# 2  1892      2   29 1892-02-29
# 3  1893      2   29        NaT
# 4  1894      2   29        NaT
# 5  1895      2   29        NaT
# 6  1896      2   29 1896-02-29
# 7  1897      2   29        NaT
# 8  1898      2   29        NaT

df = df.dropna(subset=['date'])

#    year  month  day       date
# 2  1892      2   29 1892-02-29
# 6  1896      2   29 1896-02-29
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful, it drops the rows as required. When I next sort the dataframe using `df.sort_values(by=['date'])` the rows stay in the previous order, i.e. with no obvious sorting from before, row 0 is Jan 1, row 1 is Feb 1, etc., and I'm hoping to sort into row 0 is Jan 1, row 1 is Jan 2, etc. Can this be rectified to allow for a more sortable date column?

Comment: `df = df.sort_values('date', ascending=True)` should do this for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same results when using that `sort_values()` call as well. Maybe I did something wrong in my melt of the original 31 day columns that carried over into the `pd.to_datetime()` to make the resulting datetimes only sortable on the month? When I look at the `df.info()` output it shows the day column as an object, so maybe I need to somehow convert the column to integer before calling `pd.to_datetime()`?

Comment: I've tried what I suggested above by using `df['day'].astype(int)` but it had no effect, the day column remained an object.

Comment: Try `df['day'] = pd.to_numeric(df['day'])`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually already tried `df['day'] = pd.to_numeric(df['day'], errors='coerce')` and it did the trick for converting the day column to int. However this didn't have any effect on the sorting, month is still changing ahead of day, rather than vice-versa as expected. Perhaps I should post a separate question for this issue, as it's not entirely related to the original question, which has been answered?

Comment: @JamesAdams, I think that's a good idea - seems like a separate issue altogether.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166069/discussion-between-james-adams-and-jpp).

Comment: The issue discussed in the above comments was a result of me neglecting to preface the `df.sort_values()` call with `df =`, and the sorting doesn't happen in place by default, so the sorted values went away since they weren't assigned back into the `df` variable.